# Gatling: Issue saving data to session

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am updating some performance tests that use Gatling to test the performance when a user creates an assignment with several classes in it rather than just one class which is what we test currently.

I'm entirely new to Scala and Gatling but I have managed to figure out, I think, almost everything. I just have one spot that is causing problems and perplexing the dickens out of me.

The following bit of code grabs all students that are in a given class (we call them sections). This is the existing code that works exactly as expected with the existing tests, yet for some reason the new tests always throw an error that `listOfStudents` doesn't exist.

The error to throws is `'hook-81' crashed with 'java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: listOfStudents', forwarding to the next one`

```scala
  val getListOfStudents = http("Get list of students")
    .get(BASE_URL + "/v2/sections/${sectionRefId}/rosters")
    .headers(getHeaderMap)
    .check(status.is(Ok),
      jsonPath("$.students[*].refId").findAll.transform(_.mkString(",")).saveAs("listOfStudents"))
```

I found this question, [Gatling not storing value in session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61246956/gatling-not-storing-value-in-session), that talks about session being immutable but I don't think I have any spots that would generate a new session except at the end of blocks so it shouldn't be the issue.

The original tests uses the following code to grab the list of students and the value is properly saved in this scenario:

```scala
  val createEdCtsAssignment = repeat(4) {
    exec(getTeacherSectionId)
      .exec(getListOfStudents)
      .exec(session => session.set("assignmentType", "PROGRAM_ASSESSMENT"))
      .exec(createTeacherAssignment)
  }
```

This is the code where it doesn't work:

```scala
  val createMultiSectionEdCtsAssignment = repeat(2) {
    exec(getTeacherMultiSectionSectionId)
      .exec(session => session.set("listOfStudentsBySection", ""))
      .foreach(session => session("listOfSectionRefIds").as[String].split(',').toSeq, "sectionRefId") {
        exec(session => {
          exec(getListOfStudents)
          session.set("listOfStudentsBySection", collectStudents(session))
        })
      }
      .exec(session => session.set("assignmentType", "PROGRAM_ASSESSMENT"))
      .exec(createMultiSectionTeacherAssignment)
  }
```

After adding lots of `println()`s I found the error happens in `session.set("listOfStudentsBySection", collectStudents(session))`. In `collectStudents` the failure happens at `val studentsList = session("listOfStudents").as[String]`. This is the exact same line of code that works when called in `createTeacherAssignment`. Both of those functions exist in their own files but even trying to print the value of `listOfStudents` right after `exec(getListOfStudents)` generates the same error.

The only real change between them is the presence of the `foreach` loop in the non-working version.

(Our Gatling version is 2.2.5)

I have tried everything I can find or think of with no success. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: "(Our Gatling version is 2.2.5)". Gatling 2 has been dead for years! You should upgrade (current is 3.6.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```scala
exec(session => {
  exec(getListOfStudents)
  session.set("listOfStudentsBySection", collectStudents(session))
})
```

This is completely wrong. As explained in the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/general/scenario/), you're creating a building that doesn't do anything.

This is correct:

```scala
exec(getListOfStudents)
.exec { session =>
  session.set("listOfStudentsBySection", collectStudents(session))
}
```

Then, **Gatling 2 has been DEAD for year!** Please upgrade for a modern version. The current version is 3.6.1 and 3.7.0 will be out in a few weeks.

Comment: Thanks, A colleague had just given me the same answer. Good to have it here where others can find it. This is what happens when you hand an old, large, and poorly maintained project to two engineers that are really iOS folks. We are in the midst of updating all the versions currently so I'll add Gatling to the list.

Comment: Awesome. FYI, we'll also be releasing in a few weeks a Java DSL (that can be used with Kotlin), if it helps.